# What happened to the Akshaya Patra after the exile?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, draupadi

In Mahabharata when five Pandavas & their wife went into forest for 12 years they lost the game of Chopat with Duryodhana, that time Draupadi used to cook food in a patra ( dish/bowl ) named Akshaya Patra ( Akshaya meaning never finishing ). She can get as much food as she want for their daily need. Once after Draupadi eats her meal, the Akshaya patra  stops producing food for same day.

So When Pandavas returned to their home back, what happened to that Akshaya Patra ?

Comment: Correction !! Akshay parta Won't produce food after draupadi finish her food.

Comment: @TheDictator, Thanks for the information.

Comment: Draupadi partook her food only after her husbands and guests satisfied their hunger. Akshya Patra was presented to her by Lord Surya to ensure that the guests are well fed. After the completion of the exile period, the vessel was returned to Lord Surya.

Comment: Udupi Krishna temple is famous in world for its gorgeous worship of Shri Krishna Deity. It has been established by Madhva who is a one of the counted among foremost Acharya (Spiritual Head) in India. It is said that Madhva was incarnation of Bhima himself. Madhva actually is said to have excavated the Akshaya Patra and gave it to the temple priests. It is said that it is kept there till date. You have to visit there, and if you are lucky you can get a chance to see the Akshaya Patra. It's said that due to its influence, there is a massive ongoing free food program in temple.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the references of the verses of Mahabharat of this scenario.

Here, "Surya-Dev" says that he will provide them food for 12 years.

So, according to this statement, the Akshay-patr, either lost it power after 12 years, or it went back to Surya-Dev after 12 years.

Please note that: Dharm-raj is a reference to yudhistr in this verse.
And the Akshay-patr was given only for the "van-was" of 12 years, not the agyat-was of 1 year.

[image: duration verse]
[image: powers of patr]